# Select equal number of rows for levels in categorical variable based on level length

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a 'master dataframe' with unequal observations for a categorical variable, and want to create, lets say, 20 other balanced sub-dataframes.

For these new sub-datasets, I want to keep all rows where variable x = 0, and randomly sample rows for x = 1, where x = 1 must have the same length as x = 0.

So, if we have something like this:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
y <- sample(1:25) 
df <- data.frame(x,y) # master dataframe
```

That's what I want to get:

```
df_1 <- df[sample(which(df$x=='1'), length(which(df$x=='0'))),]
df_0 <- df[df$x=='0',]
df_new <- rbind(df_1,df_0) # new balanced subdataframe
```

As I want to create n subdatasets, copy-and-paste is not practical. I've tried to find ways to do this but had no success so far. 
I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a list with 25 elements, each one a data frame of 18 observations (9 of each x value) randomly sampled from the original.

```r
library(dplyr)
l <- sum(df$x==0)

out <- lapply(1:25, function(i){
  df %>% group_by(x) %>% sample_n(size=l)
})
```

Comment: Where does `group_by` derive? It is not part of base R.

Comment: Are you creating a list inside `lapply` which returns a list?

Comment: It seems like that

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by` that subsets data frames by one or more factors and applies a function on each subset.

```
df_list <- by(df, df$x, function(sub)
   sub[sample(1:nrow(sub), length(which(df$x=='0'))),]
)

df_new <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```